# How to get all posts related to particular category name?

Tags: posts, get-posts

I am developing one project and in this project i have to display all the posts related to particular category name.

I have searched a lot but i haven't got any idea to implement this.

How can i do this so that i can display all the posts from particular category/term

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use `WP_Query()` to generate your custom query, [using the category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Assuming you know (or know how to *get*) the ID of the specific category, as `$catid`:

```
<?php
$category_query_args = array(
    'cat' => $catid
);

$category_query = new WP_Query( $category_query_args );
?>
```

Note: you could also pass the category **slug** to the query, via `category_name`, instead of `cat`.

Now, just output your loop:

```
<?php
if ( $category_query->have_posts() ) : while $category_query->have_posts() : $category_query->the_post();
// Loop output goes here
endwhile; endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on when and how exactly you want to use it - but generally speaking you can either use a custom query  , or simply use

```
if in_category('my_cat_name_or_ID') {
//do whatever
}
```

if you want to learn about custom query : http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries

Comment: yes this will work and i have done in other way

Answer (score 1):

Below code will fetch post title from particular category name.

```
 <?php 
      $myposts = get_posts(array(
      'showposts' => 8, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
      'post_type' => 'your-post-type',
      'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'term-name' //pass your term name here
                          )
                        ))
                       );

        foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
        // echo $mypost->post_title . '<br/>';
        // echo $mypost->post_content . '<br/>';
        // echo  $mypost->ID . '<br/><br/>';
        echo '<li class="faq"> <p class="title"><a href="' . get_permalink($mypost) . '">' . $mypost->post_title . '</a></p></li>';} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Query`'s [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) is, far and away, going to be the most flexible way to implement this. If you make the question a bit more specific, I should be able to crank out some sample code for you to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin ([WordPress Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-category-posts/)) for that.

WordPress Category Posts is a plugin for WordPress that creates a linked list of the posts in a specific category.

Use the following code wherever you want to list the posts for a category:

```
wp_cat_posts(get_cat_ID('your_category_name'));
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
 query_posts('category_name=my_category_name&showposts=5');
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 get_the_content();
 endwhile;
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that `get_the_content()` doesn't print anything, [please never use `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-ause-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762) unless you have a good reason for doing so.